# How to display CLI display manager after remotely stopping Lightdm?

Tags: command-line, lightdm, login-screen

I have a Raspberry Pi with a local monitor, local keyboard and mouse.
Generally I would use it as a web server, but sometimes I will watch any TV with it.

I think my Raspberry Pi heats up a little less when I turn the GUI on / off as needed.

**Scenario 1: What is my steps when I would like to use it as TV?**

1. I logg-in locally (tty1) or remotely (ssh) to Raspi
2. I start GUI with executing this command

   sudo service start lightdm
3. I open a webbrowser locally or remotely (x11vnc client)
4. Now I am able to watch something on Raspi's local monitor

**Scenario 2: What is my steps when I would like stop using TV?**

1. I logg-off locally (to tty1) or disconnect remotely (from x11vnc client)
2. I stops graphical environment with executing this command

   sudo service start lightdm

   (memmory usage decreases so heating of Raspi should be lower I think)
3. Now Raspi is working OK as a WWW server

**Where is the problem?**

- After step 3 in scenario 2, I cannot see normal console login (tty1) on local monitor. There is black screen with flashing prompt sign. I am not able to logg-in locally. Of course I can connect remotely and start lightdm. But I would like to see normal console login screen (tty1).

**What i have tested with no success?**

- shortcuts combination "CTRL + ALT + T"
- command "sudo init 3"

Please write some hints or solution to solve my problem.

Comment: What OS & release are you using?   `lightdm` hasn't been used for quite a few releases of Ubuntu

Comment: I have Ubuntu 20.04 Server + Xfce4

Comment: *"a remote session I'm still connected to"* so, you logged in via SSH and started lighdm from there... then sometime later stopped it from a GUI terminal emulator in an XFCE desktop session? is that correct? Please [edit] your question to include all the steps.

Comment: @steeldriver, i have edited my first post

Comment: If you log in via SSH when you can't get the tty1 login prompt, what does `systemctl status getty*` say?

Comment: It says that services are active https://pastebin.com/xtSCBpU8

Answer (score 0):

Solution is command

```
sudo systemctl restart getty@tty0
```